# No log entries in Azure Application Insights using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights, nlog

Goal: Forward log entries from NLog to Azure Application Insights. Starting from: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging

I created a very basic console application:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "my instrumentation key";

Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
logger.Info("Hello World");

Console.ReadLine();
```

With the following app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
  </startup>
  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="true">
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
    </extensions>
    <targets>
      <target type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" name="aiTarget" layout="${longdate} ${level} ${threadid} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=ToString}" />
      <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${longdate} ${level} ${threadid} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=ToString}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="aiTarget" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

But no log messages arrive in Azure Application Insights while the ColoredConsole target works as expected. The messages arrive only when I call `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.Flush();`.

- Did I make a configuration mistake?
- Do I need to call .Flush() by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telemetry items are buffered (for 30 seconds by default, see [the source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/Implementation/TelemetryBuffer.cs#L16_)) before the client send the data to the portal. So you have to keep the console open for at least that amount of time or call `Flush()` manually or set the [developer mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.telemetrychannel.developermode.aspx) to true:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
```

**EDIT**
There are multiple channels that can be used, like `InMemoryChannel` or `ServerTelemetryChannel`. They all have a default buffer interval of 30 seconds.

The `InMemoryChannel` for example has a public property `TimeSpan SendingInterval` so if you cast the `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel` to the actual implementation you should be able to change the buffer interval.

See [ServerTelemetryChannel.MaxTelemetryBufferDelay](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/ServerTelemetryChannel/ServerTelemetryChannel.cs#L124) and [InMemoryChannel.SendingInterval](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Channel/InMemoryChannel.cs#L75).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to configure the buffer interval? Anyway, when I call `Flush()` on application exit I can be sure that all buffered messages are send to Azure Application Insights, right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct, Flush will do that..And I am not sure about whether you can change the buffer interval. I haven't seen a way to do that yet.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! I have voted for your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet ;-).

Comment: Its recommended to do a Sleep after flush, as flush is not syncronous. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#flushing-data

Comment: ver. 2.6.0-beta3 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget/2.6.0-beta3 Allows NLog to flush the ApplicationInsights-Target by calling `NLog.LogManager.Flush()`