# TrackTrace is not logging In to Application Insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have the below code. It's Not logging to Trace.I am not sure why. If possible can you help me on this?

```
public static void SAPLogger(string Message)
        {

            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "XXX-XXX-XXX";
            TelemetryClient TelePositive = new TelemetryClient
            {
                InstrumentationKey = "XXX-XXX" (Optional Value)
            };


            //TelePositive.TrackRequest(Req);
            TelePositive.TrackTrace(Message, SeverityLevel.Verbose, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Information", "SAP" } });

        }
```

I am calling this method in the Main() method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                int a = 5;
                int c = a / 2;
                SAPLogger("The value is Success" + c);
            }
}
```

I am totally not sure why this is not logging. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No log entries in Azure Application Insights using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514679/no-log-entries-in-azure-application-insights-using-microsoft-applicationinsights)

Comment: Items are buffered, so you need to either wait, call `Flush()` or set developer mode tot true.

Comment: For this method Missed the flush but in the real application m using it. but will try with Developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your example app is probably exiting before your telemetry gets sent.

DeveloperMode *should* cause it to send immediately, however, if your process exists immediately like your test app appears to, the process might still end before the web request gets created and sent.

For short lived applications like that test app, you'll probably need a `flush` and a `sleep` call of some kind at the end to ensure telemetry has a chance to send before the app quits.

For a real application that lives for a long time, telemetry will be batched and sent after an amount of time, or number of events is met, then that batch will be sent.  you app probably still would want to flush/wait at the end just to make sure any batched up telemetry gets sent.

but in either case, the flush/wait should only occur once, at the end.  not with every call to track telemetry.

Comment: So John, can we use the thread Sleep in the Live application for each logging? isn't that going to make application slow or something?

Comment: you don't want sleep with each log, you want `flush` + `sleep` **once** at the very end, before the process ends, so that any queued up telemetry gets sent.  your example is a main that starts up, sends one event, and shuts down. is that your real app?

Comment: No real app is like, This SAPLogger(string) will be called from multiple methods catch block, thousands times maybe

Comment: if you're calling this one method over and over during the lifetime, you don't need sleep.  and unless you have other context you might be setting on the telemetry client, you might want to create just one instance of the telemetry client and reuse it, instead of re-creating the telemetry client over and over for each trace.